# Return Json of SelectList in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

I'd apreciate if someone could advise on the following:

I have my SelectList in the controller:

```
 SelectList sl = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.TraumaRepo.GetByType(type).ToList(), "Code", "Name");
```

Normally my Json returns simple strings:

```
  return Json(new[]{
                        new { value = "1", text = "item 1" },
                        new { value = "2", text = "item 2" }}, 
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can iterate through this SelectList to return its data value and data text fields as JsonResult? How to include foreach or linq into Json()?

In my View I append it to my DropDownList:

```
    $.each(data, function (value, i) {

                    ddl.append(
                            $('<option/>', {
                                value: i.value,
                                html: i.text
                            }));

                });
```

Comment: Did you try just Json(sl);

Comment: How will I append its key and value into DropDownList then? Pls, see my edits

Comment: Thanks, I found one way usiong Linq:  var list = from l in sl
                           select new { l.Value, l.Text };

Answer (score 0):

just get the JSON to serializer the list object directly

```
  return Json(_unitOfWork.TraumaRepo.GetByType(type).ToList(), 
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ActionResult to JsonResult in addition following link might help you

http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/returning_data_view_from_controller_action

one more simple json example

http://www.akhildeshpande.com/2011/08/simple-jquery-getjson-example-in-aspnet.html